# Kramdown: How can I set the location of the image?

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

As described in the [Syntax Reference](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html) of [Kramdown](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/index.html), we can set the height and width size of the image, like the below:

> `Here is an inline ![smiley](smiley.png){:height="36px" width="36px"}.`

But how can I set the location of the image, like set `align=center`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`align=center` is deprecated. Now you'd better use CSS.

In order to accomplish this, you need to put your image in a [html block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#Elements).
Your code can be :

```
<div class="img_container">
![Me]({{site.baseurl}}/img/me.jpg){: height="36px" width="36px"}
</div>
```

In your css, add :

```
.img_container{
  text-align: center;
}
```

And, in order to instruct kramdown to parse inside block html elements, in _config.yml, add :

```
kramdown:
  parse_block_html: true
```

Your image is now centered in its parent block.